# Delimitar ancho de Bottom Drawer en React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, navigation-drawer, mui

He estado indagando y no puedo encontrar un método para modificar/contener el ancho de un Drawer importado de Material UI ([SwipeableDrawer](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/#swipeable-edge)).
Mi idea era que este sea del tipo Bottom pero que no ocupe todo el ancho de la pantalla. Pude lograr que la parte superior de este sea delimitado con el uso de sx. Pero cuando este se expande sigue ocupando toda la pantalla.
Drawer Expandido y sin expandir
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta el codigo del componente:

```
import "../sheets/Drawer3.module.css";
import "../sheets/Drawer3.css";
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Global } from '@emotion/react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import { grey } from '@mui/material/colors';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import SwipeableDrawer from '@mui/material/SwipeableDrawer';

const drawerBleeding = 56;

const Root = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  height: '100%',
  backgroundColor:
    theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? grey[100] : theme.palette.background.default,
}));

const StyledBox = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? '#fff' : grey[800],
}));

const Puller = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
  width: 30,
  height: 6,
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? grey[300] : grey[900],
  borderRadius: 3,
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 8,
  left: 'calc(50% - 15px)',
}));

function Drawer3(props) {
  const { window } = props;
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleDrawer = (newOpen) => () => {
    setOpen(newOpen);
  };

  // This is used only for the example
  const container = window !== undefined ? () => window().document.body : undefined;

  return (
    <div>
    <Root >
      <CssBaseline />
      <Global
        styles={{
          '.MuiDrawer-root > .MuiPaper-root': {
            height: `calc(50% - ${drawerBleeding}px)`,
            overflow: 'visible',
          },
        }}
      />
      <Box sx={{ textAlign: 'center', pt: 1 }}>
        <Button onClick={toggleDrawer(true)}>Open</Button>
        
      </Box>
      <SwipeableDrawer 
        container={container}
        anchor="bottom"
        open={open}
        onClose={toggleDrawer(false)}
        onOpen={toggleDrawer(true)}
        swipeAreaWidth={drawerBleeding}
        disableSwipeToOpen={false}
        ModalProps={{
        keepMounted: true,
        }}
      >
        <StyledBox 
          sx={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: -drawerBleeding,
            borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
            borderTopRightRadius: 10,
            visibility: 'visible',
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
            margin: "auto",
            width: 350,
          }}
        >
          <Puller />
          <Typography sx={{ p: 2, color: 'text.secondary' }}>51 results</Typography>
        </StyledBox>
        
      </SwipeableDrawer>
    </Root>
    </div>
  );
}

Drawer3.propTypes = {
  window: PropTypes.func,
};

export default Drawer3;
```

He revisado la documentación de Material Ui y no encontré ningún prop que modifique el ancho.
Desde ya agradezco la atención

Answer (score 0):

Add width and left property inside Global as per below code.

```
    <Global
  styles={{
    '.MuiDrawer-root > .MuiPaper-root': {
      height: `calc(50% - ${drawerBleeding}px)`,
      width:350,
      left: `calc(50% - 175px)`,
      overflow: 'visible',
    },
  }}
/>
```